# If for a complex function if $f^{(n)}(1/k)=0$ $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$, then $f(z)$ is a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, solution-verification

$\mathbf{Question}:$ For a function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ and $n \geq 1$, let $f^{(n)}$ denote the $n$th derivative of $f$ and $f^{(0)}=f$.
Let $f$ be an entire function such that for some $n\geq 1$, $f^{(n)}(\frac{1}{k})=0$, $\ \forall k\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $f$ is a polynomial.

$\mathbf{Attempt}:$ $f$ being an entire function, we can express $f$ as $f(z)= \displaystyle\sum_{t=0}^\infty a_tz^t $.

We get $f^{(n)}(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{t=n}^\infty t(t-1)...(t-n+1)a_t z^{t-n}$

Firstly, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{k \to \infty}f^{(n)}\bigg(\frac{1}{k}\bigg)=n!a_n=0 \implies a_n=0$ ($k$ is natural)

Now, for $f^{(n)}(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{t=n+1}^\infty t(t-1)...(t-n+1)a_t z^{t-n}= z\displaystyle\sum_{t=n+1}^\infty t(t-1)...(t-n+1)a_tz^{t-n-1} \ $, and for $z=1/k$, $f^{(n)}(\frac{1}{k})=0 \implies \displaystyle\sum_{t=n+1}^\infty t(t-1)...(t-n+1)a_t\bigg(\frac{1}{k}\bigg)^{t-n-1}=0  $. Again, taking $k \to \infty $, we get $a_{n+1}=0$.

Let $a_{n+m}=0$. Then $f^{(n)}(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{t=n+m+1}^\infty t(t-1)...(t-n+1)a_t z^{t-n}=z^{m+1}\displaystyle\sum_{t=n+m+1}^\infty t(t-1)...(t-n+1)a_t z^{t-n-m-1}$

Now, $(\frac{1}{k})^{m+1}\displaystyle\sum_{t=n+m+1}^\infty t(t-1)...(t-n+1)a_t (1/k)^{t-n-m-1}=0 \implies \displaystyle\sum_{t=n+m+1}^\infty t(t-1)...(t-n+1)a_t (1/k)^{t-n-m-1}=0 $. Taking $\displaystyle\lim_{k \to ∞}\sum_{t=n+m+1}^\infty t(t-1)...(t-n+1)a_t (1/k)^{t-n-m-1}=0$, we are left with $a_{n+m+1}=0$.

Thus we conclude that $a_{n+p}=0$ for all $p \in \mathbb{N}$

Now, $f^{(n)}(z)=0$, which gives us $f(z)=c_0+c_1z+...c_{n-1}z^{n-1}$.

Is this method correct?

Kindly $\mathbf{Verify}$

PS: I am aware of the duplicates, I just want to get my method checked without me looking at the previously answered questions.

Comment: It suffices to treat the case $n=0$ as an entire function is polynomial iff its derivative is polynomial

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I am not quite getting it, could you please explain a bit?

Answer (score 2):

What's the point of all this over-complication?

$f$ is entire $\implies f^{(n)}$ is entire. Now $\{\frac{1}{k}\}_{k \ge 1} \subset \Bbb C$ has a limit point in $\Bbb C$ (which is connected), and $f^{(n)}$ being entire vanishes on $\{\frac{1}{k}:{k \ge 1}\} $ . Hence by Uniqueness principle, $f^{(n)} \equiv 0 \implies$ $f^{(n-1)}$ is a constant $\implies$ $f^{(n-2)}$ is a polynomial of degree at most 1 $\implies \dots \implies f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $(n-1)$

Comment: I did not know about the Uniqueness Principle.

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas Okay, but learn it. That result captures the very essence of doing Complex Analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Write $g(z) = f^{(n)}(z)$ where $n$ has the property you described. The zeros of a nonconstant analytic function are isolated. Consider the sequence $a_k = \frac{1}{k}$, then since $g$ is analytic we find that
$$g(0) = \lim_{k\to \infty} g(a_k) = \lim_{k\to \infty
}0 = 0$$
Thus $0$ is not an isolated zero of $g$. We conclude that since $g$ is analytic, then it is constant and in particular $g= 0$. Now the power series representation in a domain about a point is unique. From here we can work backwards using antiderivatives to determine that $g(z) = c_o + c_1z + \ldots + c_{n-1}z^{n-1}$.

Edit: Sorry, just saw your request to verify. You should be more clear what is going on with your first statement. I think you are trying to show that $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ and thus you find that the constant term is zero? For the second part, I think it would be clearer if you said "$f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ and we have shown that the constant term is zero.... we can write the expansion as $f^{(n)}(z) = z\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \alpha_k z^{k-n-1}$. Well $f^{(n)}(\frac{1}{k}) = (\frac{1}{k})\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \alpha_k z^{k-n-1} = 0$. Thus $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \alpha_k z^{k-n-1} = 0$ whenever $z\in\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$". I think this is what you are doing and then say iterate?

Comment: Precisely so. But in addition, I am taking $\lim k \to \infty$ (while $k$ is taken over the natural numbers only), so that $\alpha_{n+1}$ is the only remaining term on the left hand side for $z=1/k$ and the right hand side is $0$

Comment: Would that be alright?

Comment: I think you will be alright as long as you are clear where the induction step is

Comment: I tried to prove that if a zero of an analytical function is non-isolated, then it must be constant. But it has remained unanswered (verification request). It would be of great help if you could check that out as well. My approach has been very similar to this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3762284/389992

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me so far. Just for a final bit, I've made the inductive step much clearer now.

Comment: Kindly let me know if that is good enough.